# Converting from RPi.GPIO to circuit python digitalio

Tags: gpio, pi-4, python-3, adafruit

I didn't write this code (just made some modifications) but it was using a depreciated library so I'm trying to update to the official circuit python libraries and update everything for python3.

This is for a kiln controller that I've been using successfully for a year.  It was using some deprecated libraries however, and recent updates broke things.   It seems redundant import both RPi.GPIO and digitalio.   Since the max31856 requires digitalio, I thought I'd convert the code to use that instead of RPi.GPIO.  However, the code just doesn't seem as elegant.   I'm wondering if I'm missing something or if I should just keep using Rpi.GPIO?

The HEAT = (23,24) is the the output pins to trigger the relays for the elements.   This should be expandable because some kilns use more than 2 elements.

This is the original code

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
HEAT = (23, 24)
for element in HEAT:
    GPIO.setup(element, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(element, GPIO.LOW)
```

And to turn the elements on and off

```
for element in HEAT:
        GPIO.output(element, False)
```

and

```
for element in HEAT:
        GPIO.output(element, True)
```

The code I'm comming up with is something like this

```
HEAT = (board.D23,board.D24)
for element in HEAT:
        element = digitalio.DigitalInOut(element)
        element.direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT
        element.value = False
```

I haven't actually tested this to make sure it's triggering both elements but it doesn't generate any errors when I run it.

Is there a better way to do this?   I've tried running digitalio.DigitalInOut(element) with various combinations to avoid the board.D23 in the list but circuit python didn't like those.

Here is the entire code base.   https://github.com/fayena/PILN

Suggestions?

Comment: RPi.GPIO is better supported and as it's part of RaspiOS should always work on any current or future version of the RPi.

Comment: So, I would be better off continuing to use the RPi.GPIO interface for the kiln element pins for the sake of future compatibility/more elegant code even though I'm importing two input/output interfaces? 

Sorry if these are basic questions, I'm self taught and couldn't find these particular questions addressed anywhere in my searches.

Comment: You would be better supported that way.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: Please create an answer about the solution to your question and accept it after two days with a click on the tick on its left side. There is nothing wrong with self-answering. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP noted in a comment that she/he would be better supported with this way:

> I would be better off continuing to use the RPi.GPIO interface for the kiln element pins for the sake of future compatibility/more elegant code even though I'm importing two input/output interfaces.